# Can't load Properties even though ClassLoader.getResource found the .properties file

Tags: eclipse, properties, annotations, velocity, processor

I've been struggling with this problem: 
I'm trying to write an annotation processor (using Eclipse IDE) that should
1 - recognize the annotation and process it - writes message that annotation was found
2 - generate new source file using velocity template engine

(using this tutorial: http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/annotation-generators/)

I export it to the .jar and use with another client class. Step 1 is successful, but when resolving step 2 I cannot get past these lines:

```
Properties props = new Properties();  
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("velocity.properties");
messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, url.toString());  
props.load(url.openStream());  
messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,"Properties loaded.");
```

url.toString() works fine and it seams that "velocity.properties" was found:

*jar:file:/C:/Users/Zuz/workspace/Procesor_B/zh.procesor.b.jar!/velocity.properties*

But the second message ("Properties loaded.") never shows up. Nor anything after that works. No file is generated. I assume something must have gone wrong in

*props.load(url.openStream());*

I have three annotations in client class and when I process them it goes like this:
found 1st annotation - velocity.properties found - skips from props.load(url.openStream()) till the end of loop.
Founds 2nd annotation - the same repeats.
Founds 3rd annotation - the same repeats.

**EDIT: This is the exception I get:**

```
JAR entry velocity.properties not found in C:\Users\Zuz\workspace\Procesor_B\zh.procesor.b.jar  
java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry velocity.properties not found in C:\Users\Zuz\workspace\Procesor_B\zh.procesor.b.jar
```

I also tried this:

```
props.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("velocity.properties"));
```

But I got: 
    `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Below you will find further information about both processor and client class. Thanks in advance for any help!

**Here's my source code for Annotation Processor - doesn't do anything useful right now:**

```
    package zh.procesor.b;    

all necessary java, javax imports ommitted for length
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;

import zh.anotacia.b.Anotacia_B;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("zh.anotacia.b.Anotacia_B")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class Procesor_B extends AbstractProcessor{

private static final Logger LOG =
        Logger.getLogger(Procesor_B.class.getName());

private Filer file; 
private Messager messager;


@Override
public void init(ProcessingEnvironment env){    
    file = env.getFiler();
    messager = env.getMessager();

}

@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
        RoundEnvironment roundEnv)  {
    String className = "Trieda"; 
    String packageName = "Package";
    int i = 1; 

    for (Element elem: roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Anotacia_B.class)){
        i++;
        Anotacia_B anot = elem.getAnnotation(Anotacia_B.class);
        String message = "Annotation found in : " + elem.getSimpleName();
        messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, message);

        try{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResource("velocity.properties");

        messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, url.toString());

        //from here it is not working
        props.load(url.openStream());
        messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "Properties loaded.");

        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine(props);
        ve.init(); 

        VelocityContext vc = new VelocityContext();
        vc.put("className", className+i);
        vc.put("packageName", packageName+i);

        Template vt = ve.getTemplate("testtemplate.vm");

        JavaFileObject jfo = file.createSourceFile(
                packageName + "." + className + "Info");

        messager.printMessage(
                Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,
                "creating source file: " + jfo.toUri());

        Writer writer = jfo.openWriter();

        messager.printMessage(
                Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE,
                "applying velocity template: " + vt.getName());

        vt.merge(vc, writer);

        writer.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, ex.getMessage());
            messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                                  "Stacktrace: " + ex.toString());  
            messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,  
                                  ex.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }         
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Here's the client class:**

```
    package zh.trieda.b;  

import zh.anotacia.b.Anotacia_B;

@Anotacia_B(vstup = "50", vystup = "50")
public class Rad {  

@Anotacia_B(vstup = "10", vystup = "15")
public void basic(){
    // do something
    }  

@Anotacia_B(vstup = "2", vystup = "30")
public void premium(){
    // do something
    }
}
```

I'm new here, so I'm not allowed to put pictures, but here's one link with picture for
Procesor_B structure, Client class Trieda_B structure, Factory Path of Trieda_B

http://bkmbj.wz.cz/structures.jpg

**Here's what's in velocity.properties:**

```
runtime.log.logsystem.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.SystemLogChute
resource.loader = classpath
classpath.resource.loader.class =     org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
```

Comment: `props.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("velocity.properties");` should work. What's the result? Exceptions?

Comment: `ex.getMessage(); ex.getStackTrace();` doesn't print the exceptions, those lines don't do anything useful. Can you print them to see the actual exceptions?

Comment: @MarcelStör @SergiuDumitriu `props.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("velocity.prope‌​rties");` worked well! Thanks! However, when trying to procede, it still skips executing code from Velocity Engine init() 'till the end of cyclus. The Exception I get is this one: `org.apache.velocity.exception.VelocityException: 'Error initializing log: Failed to initialize an instance of org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute with the current runtime configuration.` Any ideas about that?

Comment: @MarcelStör I couldn't accept the answer because when I tried once again I started to get NullpointerException (using ResourceAsStream) or FileNotFound (when using getResource). I have no idea why. Everything else is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
props.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("velocity.prope‌​rties");
```

should work.